# HTML Select Option Value Not Updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML form with the following select element in it:

```
<select class="form-control" onchange="$('form#filter').submit()" id="sort" name="sort">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">A - Z</option>
    <option value="1">Z - A</option>
</select>
```

The issue is that when I select a different option, the HTML doesn't update and set the option I chose as the selected option.

I have absolutely no idea why it isn't updating and I've been at it for hours now.

This is the function that is bound to the submit event on the form in case you need it:

```
$("form#filter").on("submit", function(evt)
{
    var form = $(this);
    var target = $("div#bands");

    var url = form.attr("action") + "/" + form.find('option[selected]').val();
    console.log(url);

    $.get(url).done(function(data)
    {
        target.html(data);
    });

    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: when you console log url you got the right url for each select??

Comment: Feels like I'm looking at 50% of the code. creating a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would help me helping you

Comment: Not 100% sure but try `onchange="this.form.submit();"` also `.find('option:selected')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
form.find("option[selected]").val()
```

to

```
form.find("option:selected").val()
```

or:

```
form.find("select").val()
```

or:

```
$("#sort").val()
```

The selector `option[selected]` doesn't find the option that's currently selected, it finds the option that has the `selected` attribute in the DOM (this is normally the one with the `selected` attribute in the HTML, although it's possible to change it using Javascript).

Comment: To add to this - the difference is that the selected attribute, sent with the HTML from the server, defines what option is initially selected. There is a separate selected property (not attribute) that is set on the currently selected option, but the HTML itself isn't changed to move the attribute to the newly selected option.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this worked, and thanks also for explaining why I was encountering the error

Comment: $("#sort")val()    should be    $("#sort").val()

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is incorrect. Here is a correct solution (tested on latest JQuery and Bootstrap at time of writing):

```
$("#mySelect").find("option:selected").val();
```

Thanks to Barmar for the inspiration, though only 1 of the 4 suggestions works, and only by accident. But I adapted that to log out the correct value attribute for the *currently* selected option. (The selected state of the *initial* option does **not** update when using the dropdown, see Chris O'Kelly's comment.)